# Is it possible to modify a Site Templete and reflect all the changies to the underlying Subites

Tags: development, site-template, configuration, sub-site

I have created a new sub-site, and i added many apps inside it ,, then i saved the site as template.

After that I created 5 sub-sites and i based them on the template.

now i need to add an additional Issue Tracking list to the template, so is there a way to modify the template , then add the new issue tracking list and automatically have the issue tracking list added on the 5 sub-sites ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change anything in Site Template after you have created the sites using that template. Then you need to manually update the changes in each of the sites you created. Because there is no way to do this.

You need to make sure all the changes are added on the site template first and then you need to create the sites accordingly.

Refer this article for more details: [SharePoint Site Templates](http://windowsitpro.com/windows/customizing-sharepoint-site-templates)

Comment: R but i did not create the site template from scratch,, what i did is that i created a normal sub site (SiteA), then i save it as a template. after that i created a new sub site (SiteB) based on the template. so now you mention that i need to update the template,, so can i modify siteA, update the template accordingly and then apply the changes to subsiteB ,, not sure i understand the situation ??

Comment: No you can't have changes in the existing sites which is created by that site template. So If you have site template of `Site A`, and create 2-3 sites (`Site B`, `Site C`) of it. After that you modify the template of `Site A`, it will not effect those changes in `Site B` or `Site C`. The same logic will be applicable here.

Comment: Now let say after creating 5 sub-sites based on the template,,  we decide that we need to add extra columns to one of the apps inside the template,, so in this case i need to modify the 5 sub-sites' app and add the extra columns on each subsite separately  ? is this correct ? and then i can modify the template itself and add the extra columns to it, so new subsites that are based on the template  will have the extra column from the begging ?? is this correct?

Comment: **1st Question:** Yes, that is correct. You have to put changes in each subsite separately. **2nd Question:** Yes, that is correct too. Means you change something in template and then you create the site using that template then those new sites will have the extra columns in it.